# Can not use windowFullscreen to Android Dialog

Tags: android, dialog, styles

When I creat a Dialog with follow styles:

```
<style name="Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/transparent_background</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@+android:style/Animation.Translucent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>  
</style>
```

I found that windowFullscreen item could not work!!
How can I creat a floating Dialog with fullscreen just like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Zshd.jpg

Comment: You can use Dialog Fragment  [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#FullscreenDialog)